# Should I make my Prism views a special View class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, prism-4

I normally just use `UserControl` for a view, but during this project I thought it might be better to derive a `View` class from that, and use that as the 'containing' class for views, to allow me to possibly later inject more functionality into a `View`. However, I wasn't using Prism then, so I had much fewer luxuries etc. that an established framework brings.

Should I keep this practice, or are plain `UserControl` views ample enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a matter of the requirements for your Views. As you said, that approach gives you the flexibility of adding functionality to your `View` class and having it instantly available in all your Views.

However, as the focus in the View is usually put in maximizing the XAML and minimizing the code-behind (a good example for this are behaviors), I think your common base `View` class approach might somehow move you in the other direction. Whatever you'd put into that class, try to achieve it through XAML and behaviors.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at behaviours. I've not explored them yet.